# MS Access DB Insert Query Not Working

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to insert Data into MS ACCESS DB. Everything is fine. Connection, DB Path etc.
There is a table ***CIT*** in it. 
I am using this `Insert into` query

```
string query = "INSERT INTO CIT (GRNO:, Name, FName, CNIC, Address, ContactNO, Gender, Qualification, DOB, RegDate, Photo) VALUES ('" + txtGRNO.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtFName.Text + "','1234','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + cBoxGender.Text + "','" + cBoxQual.Text + "','" + dteDOB.Text + "','" + dteReg.Text + "','" + path + "');";
```

I tried everything but cant seem to find what is wrong here. The datatype of fields is Text in DB, & when I execute the query , it gives the error
[image: Syntax Error in MS Access]

Comment: Why dont you use `string.Format()` or `command parameter`!

Comment: can you check all columns are text datatype?

Answer (score 1):

Your table includes 2 fields whose names are problematic: `GRNO:`; and `Name`.

Since `GRNO:` includes a colon, you can enclose it in square brackets so the db engine will accept it: `[GRNO:]`

And since `Name` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html), enclose that one in square brackets, too.

```
"INSERT INTO CIT ([GRNO:], [Name], ...
```

Beyond those field name issues, the standard advice is to use a parameter query for your `INSERT`.  Note you will still need to bracket those problem names in a parameter query.

Also, Access will let you use back-ticks instead of square brackets if you prefer ...

```
"INSERT INTO CIT (`GRNO:`, `Name`, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO CIT (GRNO, Name, FName, CNIC, Address, ContactNO, Gender, Qualification, DOB, RegDate, Photo) VALUES ('" + txtGRNO.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtFName.Text + "','1234','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + cBoxGender.Text + "','" + cBoxQual.Text + "','" + dteDOB.Text + "','" + dteReg.Text + "','" + path + "');";
```

Remove `;` after `GRNO` field.

Comment: BTW thats not ; it is ' : ' . Which is used in DB column